# Is it possible to obtain a MediaStream from a video-js tag element?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, video.js, mediastream

Is it possible to obtain a MediaStream or atleast a `VideoFrame` from a `video-js` tag element just like we would obtain from html `video` tags via captureStream() method?

My objective is to send the stream via a WebRTC PeerConnection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get MediaStream from a live videojs hls streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226070/get-mediastream-from-a-live-videojs-hls-streaming)

Comment: I saw that before and it involves changing video-js tag into a regular html video tag which is not possible in my case.

Comment: there'll be a `<video>` element inside the `<video-js>` after the player has initialised

Comment: @misterben yes there is. Thank you very much.